# Is it possible to run 'unshare -n [program]' as an unprivileged user?

Tags: networking, privileges, namespace

I want to run a program without any internet access, e.g.

`unshare -n ping 127.0.0.1`.

As an unprivileged user, it returns `Operation not permitted`, as a privileged user, it returns the desired `Network is unreachable`.

Is there any way to make it work for the unprivileged user, as well?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In later versions of util-linux, `unshare` gained the `--map-root-user` option. Quoting from `unshare(1)` version 2.26.2:

> -r, --map-root-user
>
> Run  the  program  only after the current effective user and group IDs have been mapped to the superuser UID and GID in the newly created user namespace.  This makes it possible to conveniently gain capabilities needed to manage various aspects of  the  newly created  namespaces (such as configuring interfaces in the network namespace or mounting filesystems in the mount namespace) even when run unprivileged.  As a mere convenience feature, it does not support more sophisticated use cases, such as mapping multiple ranges of UIDs and GIDs.  This option implies --setgroups=deny.

So, on newer systems, you can run:

```
unshare -n -r ping 127.0.0.1
```

And this will yield the expected `Network is unreachable`.

On Debian systems you might still get an `Operation not permitted` error, then you have to enable unprivileged user namespaces first by running:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

Note: for a wider range of use cases, the more sophisticated `bwrap --unshare-net` may be considered, as described briefly [in a different answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559392/147685).

Comment: I'm still getting `Operation not permitted` with `~$ unshare -n -r ping 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @ArcticKona your system may be configured differently from ours, sorry I can’t help. For some use cases, it may also be worth trying my other answer with `bwrap --unshare-net`, but keep in mind that ICMP (ping) is specifically not supported in that solution.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to enter a new network namespace, besides `unshare -n`, is using the higher-level Bubblewrap (`bwrap --unshare-net`):

```
bwrap --bind / / --dev /dev --unshare-net -- your-program args …
```

Note: if `your-program args …` is `ping 127.0.0.1`, you will notice that ICMP is not supported under Bubblewrap, so the OP example will not show “`Network is unreachable`”.

Also interesting to note is that programs in `--unshare-net` *do* get a loopback interface, but it’s a network namespace-isolated one.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `setcap` utility to setup unshare.

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_admin+ep /usr/bin/unshare
```

After this you can use `unshare -n ping 127.0.0.1`
I can't explain it any further and I do not know if this is a good idea, but it works and `whoami` does not show `root` as user name.

Comment: This is similar to the setuid approach, but instead of always running `unshare` as root, it always runs it with the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability, regardless of whether the user has it. This is better than setuid, but still could, in the case of a vuln. in `unshare`, lead to some privilege escalation.